# Firebird can't connect to host

Tags: networking, firebird

I'm new in FirebirdSQL. I can't connect into my host address whereas it can connect to localhost successfully. It prompt show errors like this:

```
SQL> connect "192.168.1.50:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb" user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08006
Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.1.50".
-Failed to establish a connection.
```

I have Googled about this for almost a week but I can't find the absolute way to solve this problem. My ufw firewall already deactivated, the port 3050 is opened, but it still can't connect into my host address, but easily connect to the 127.0.0.1. The Firebird classic server is running on Lubuntu Desktop 14.04.1 and the version of Firebird is 2.5.

This problem occured since I reinstall/upgrading my OS from 13.xxx into 14.xxx Lubuntu version. On the previous OS, I never facing an error like this.

What's going wrong here? Whether this problem related to OS version, or just a dumb error that I can't solve, I don't know and I very need an help from the experts, please.

Any help would be very appreciated, thank a lot in advance.

Comment: Here could be an answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/423640/firebird-connection-refused It helped me in same situation

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on *Ubuntu 16.04 LTS* with Firebird 2.5.5 and resolved it as follows:

As a user with sufficient permissions, edit the **firebird.conf** file.

```
sudo -i
vi ./firebird/2.5/firebird.conf
```

Search for 'bind' and read the comments associated with **RemoteBindAddress**.  Basically you have to reverse the # commented lines in order to allow network access to machine further away than yourself/localhost.

After adjusting the RemoteBindAddress, *restart* the Firebird service/daemon.

```
sudo service firebird2.5-super stop
sudo service firebird2.5-super start
```

Then try to connect.  I had installed the sample files so this database name worked for me: 192.168.0.12:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/employee.fdb

Note: if the machine with FirebirdSQL is behind a firewall, port 3050 must be open in order for clients to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit  file "/etc/firebird/2.5/firebird.conf" and comment the line:

```
RemoteBindAddress = localhost
```

Like this

```
#RemoteBindAddress = localhost
```

Restart the firebird:

service firebird2.5-superclassic restart

- Im using superclassic version

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  This solution looks like essentially what Chloe Tempo's answer suggests.  The intention is that each answer provide a solution that is substantively different from what has already been contributed.  Can you clarify what is different from the other answer?  Thanks.

Comment: To me, it looks like it's more detailed. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Add Windows Firewall Settings.

Go to **Start** --> **control panel** --> **Windows Firewall** --> goto **Exceptions** tab -- > Click **Add Program** --> and select **C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbguard.exe**

same way add **C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\bin\fbserver.exe** now **Restart you system** and **check from client to server firebird connection**.

Comment: The OP clearly sayd that the `Firebird` server is running under Ubuntu, not Windows.